# Python: does the set class "leak" when items are removed, like a dict?

Tags: python, set, dictionary

I know that Python `dict`s will "leak" when items are removed (because the item's slot will be overwritten with the magic "removed" value)… But will the `set` class behave the same way? Is it safe to keep a `set` around, adding and removing stuff from it over time?

**Edit**: Alright, I've tried it out, and here's what I found:

```
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> nums = range(1000000)
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 20 megs
### A baseline measurement
>>> s = set(nums)
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 36 megs
>>> for n in nums: s.remove(n)
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 36 megs
### Memory usage doesn't drop after removing every item from the set…
>>> s = None
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 20 megs
### … but nulling the reference to the set *does* free the memory.
>>> s = set(nums)
>>> for n in nums: s.remove(n)
>>> for n in nums: s.add(n)
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 36 megs
### Removing then re-adding keys uses a constant amount of memory…
>>> for n in nums: s.remove(n)
>>> for n in nums: s.add(n+1000000)
>>> gc.collect()
0
### rsize: 47 megs
### … but adding new keys uses more memory.
```

Comment: Could you substantiate what you mean when you say that Python dicts will "leak"? Perhaps a reference to another source?

Comment: AFAIK dicts don't really leak - from time to time (when you set new items for instance) the dummies that replace removed values are purget

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `set` is basically a hash table just like `dict` -- the differences at the interface don't imply many differences "below" it.  Once in a while, you should copy the set -- `myset = set(myset)` -- just like you should for a dict on which many additions and removals are regularly made over time.

Comment: @Anurag, dict can consume growing amount of memory and slow things down if you keep adding and removing keys in a long-running program.

Comment: Calling this behavior "leak" is over-simplifying and misleading, but the point is that making a fresh copy once in a while for a high-churn dict or set can save memory *and* speed things up!

Answer (score -1):

For questions like these it is often best to run a quick experiment like this one and see what happens:

```
s = set()
for a in range(1000):
  for b in range(10000000):
    s.add(b)
  for b in range(10000000):
    s.remove(b)
```

What docs and people say and what behaviour actually is are often at odds.  If this is important for you, test it.  Don't rely on others.

Comment: For the record I'm seeing no evidence of a leak in that code.  Memory use jumped up once and then stayed flat.

Comment: normally I'd agree… But when the person doing the telling is Alex Martelli, I'm going to just go ahead and believe him.

Comment: yes, that's the problem - at the end (after all the stuff has been removed), it should drop down again. And being a GC'd language, it's harder to know when all the memory that *could* be reclaimed *has* been reclaimed.

Comment: @David Wolever - the test needs to be altered according to what you're testing for.  The point was that you need to test, not that this particular test was the one to run. ;)